# Get-ProjectType is very slow in T4 Template

Tags: powershell, t4

Calling `Get-ProjectType` from a T4 Template in Visual Studio is very slow (upwards of 15 seconds).  Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: Have you tried to access project information by calling it via C#/VB code classes (VS Automation model) in your T4 code blocks? Or is using Powershell scripts a must-have?

Comment: I am just using the T4 templates to automate some scaffolding.  I assume you are talking about EnvDTE?  Is it going to be faster?  I am not sure the problem is powershell.  It might just be EnvDTE.

Comment: I usually use the EnvDTE and haven't noticed any slowdowns as you describe them. Maybe it's worth a try. At least you could rule out Powershell as the bottleneck, if you compare both variants.